# Is this a good approach to work with the MVC pattern and Express.js?

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, express

I would like to have opinions/suggestions whether this is a good way to implement/enhance the MVC pattern with Node.js and Express.js

1) I initialize the app normaly, but at this stage I call a function I named `routeRegistrar`, as follows:

```
var 
    express = require('express'),
    routeRegistrar = require('./routeRegistrar'),

var app = express.createServer();

configureApp(app);
routeRegistrar(app); //note this line

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("App started");
});

function configureApp(app){
    app.configure(function(){
        //configuration stuff with app variable
    });
}
```

2) I adopt the convention that every controller will be placed on a directory called `Controllers`, and that every controller is constituted by a module that contains one or more actions, pushed to the `exports` variable as an object following the above convention:

```
{ method: 'GET', url: '/example', action: function(req, res){  } }
```

So this way I can automatize the route registering process, and also keep the method/url close to the code that handles the request (I think its easier to read/maintain). So the code for the `routeRegistrar` is the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(app){
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/controllers').forEach(function(controllerName){
        var controller = require("./controllers/" + controllerName);

        for (var actionName in controller) {
            var action = controller[actionName];
            app[action.method](action.url, action.action);
        }
    });
}
```

And simple a indexController would look like this:

```
exports.index = {
    url: "/",
    method: "get",
    action: function(req, res){
      res.render('index');
    }
}
```

IMHO I believe this is a better approach to every time I wanted a new controller/route registered I had to

1- open app.js
2- place another require line at the top
3- write code like `app.get('/index', indexController.index);`

Please, let me know wheter this is a good way to continue the project, I would like to hear your opinions and suggestions.

**EDIT:**
Based on Tyrsius answer and the lack of another opinions I will use his approach with some modifications:

routeRegistrar.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(app){
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/controllers').forEach(function(controllerName){
    var controller = require("./controllers/" + controllerName);

    for (var actionName in controller) {
            controller[actionName](app);
        }
    });
};
```

indexController.js

```
module.exports.index = function(app){
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.send("New approach!");
    });
};
```

Comment: I'd take a look at [express-resource](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource/) if I were in your shoes -- it's a nice take on this, IMO. But yeah, I don't find any faults in your design. Edit: Just saw your edit. Myself I like to enumerate my routes explicitly. But it's a matter of taste. Although you could auto-load express-resource modules as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bad solution, but I think making your own syntax for routes will be confusing. Being able to use the same route syntax that Node/Express are used to will help you out in the long run. You won't be unfamiliar with it when you go to a new project, and you will be able to ask for help since you will be using the syntax everyone else does.

I use a similar solution, it looks like this. It will grab every .js file in the `/routes` directory at startup, so you can add controllers without needing to change any code.

in app.js

```
// Routes
require('./routes')(app);
```

routes/index.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(app){

    //GET home page
    app.get('/', function(req, res){        
        res.render('index');
    });

    //Load other controllers/routes
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(file) {
        if (file == "index.js") return;
        //var name = file.substr(0, file.indexOf('.'));
        require(__dirname + '/' + file)(app);
    });
};
```

example route/controller:

```
module.exports = function(app){

   app.post('/login', function(req, res){
        //stuff
    });

    //other actions on this route
};
```

Comment: This is a good sugestion @Tyrsius, your sugestion is pretty similiar the approach I use with the benefits you addressed. Thanks! +1